# Do the amphtml and canonical urls need to match?

Tags: amp-html

First off I apologize if this has already been asked, I attempted to search and haven't seen anything directly asking and/or answering this question.

Does the amphtml and the canonical url of content "have" to match?

Ex:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://self.com/self.html" />

<link rel="canonical" href="http://someotherwebsite.com" />
```

From reading and researching, the only thing that appears to matter is that the content needs to match.

Per the docs and researching errors;

> The content of the AMP page and its canonical web page should be essentially the same. The text need not be identical, but the topic should be the same, and users should be able to accomplish the same tasks on both the AMP and the canonical page.

If the urls do not need to match, does having different urls affect google rankings and/or any ad operations?

Comment: There is no formal restrictions but Google recommends that AMP pages should be served from the same domain as canonical pages do.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [RFC 6596 - The Canonical Link Relation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596), under section "3. The Canonical Link Relation" you will see that canonical links can point to resources that can "Exist on a different hostname or domain."

And on the AMP HTML Specification page, under [AMP document discovery](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec#amp-document-discovery) there is no extra requirement, so you might want to give it a try and report back here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's exactly what I was reading yesterday, but I wasn't able to see anything definitive directly on the AMP site. Making the change isn't 100% feasible atm, but I'll see if we can do some science and try to report back.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical and the AMP are permitted to be on different domains or subdomains. You can always prove that the same entity owns both pages because the canonical points to the AMP and the AMP points to the canonical.